# fetching data uniquely by php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

when i am using this code

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata where id='$id'");

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   echo $rows['username'];
}
```

this shows a blank page but when i am using this code

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata where id=22");

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){   
    echo $rows['username'];
}
```

this is showing me username but my question is why ist code is not showing the username

Comment: First check whether you're getting any *id* from `$_GET` superglobal or not. Do `var_dump($_GET);`.

Comment: First stop using a deprecated API

Comment: after adding this..it show array(0) { }

Comment: @RajdeepPaul if i am not getting id from $_GET then what i should do to get id??????

Comment: Just to be sure... are you opening your page in the browser with `?id=22` at the end of the URL? Or maybe better question: what is your URL in browser?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil no i am not using ?id=22  at the end..url is simple fetchdata.php

Comment: Well... if you make the URL to look like `...fetchdata.php?id=22`, it starts working, does it not?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil actually i don't want only 22..it should be any id which is stored in my database

Comment: @JiriHrazdil thanks...itz done

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thanks i learn smthng new frm u which is really helpful for me

Comment: Note: SQL INJECTION! Use `prepared-statements`

Answer (score -1):

It's because in the first code block you're putting the $id in quote marks, which converts this to a string, but it's an integer.

Trying using this instead:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata where id=$id");
```

So you're using `$id` instead of `'$id'`.

Comment: after removing the quotes it show error but  my id contain only integer value then why it showing error??????

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: You need to check your database. As that query should work if those tables and data exist

Comment: If you omit apostrophes around `$id` in the query and the `$id` is empty, you get a SQL syntax error and subsequently the warning you mention.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is failing now is because `$id` does not have a value. As you're using `$_GET` you need to call your script like so: `script.php?id=22`